# Is it possible to compute this integral with residue theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

[image: domain r : circle with radius 1 centered at 5]

First, I tried to find singularity. So I have to solve the equation z^4 + i = 0

I make z = re^(i(theta)) as polar coordinates and I found all of solution of equation is on Unit circle. Since it is not on the domain, by Cauchy's theorem I compute this integral to 0.

Is there any problem with this?

Comment: Sorry ! Domain r is circle with radius 1 centered at 5.

Comment: No problem with using Cauchy's theorem to deduce the value of zero for the integral.  That is correct.

Comment: If I have to solve this problem with residue theorem, how can I solve this?